# Trying to show radiobuttonlist as buttonlist in Yii, hiding radiobuttons in mutliple form is not working

Tags: javascript, yii

In yii, I am trying to wrap a label around a radiobutton for a radiobutton list, see no options in template. Basically want to display radio buttons as buttons in a mutliple form page. hiding radiobuttons is not working.

Comment: could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Figured it out..!! the form recognizes the label. In yii, the form elements created are in the {label} {input} template or vice versa format. If the input is within the label, it would be easier,.. so using javascript next(), I got the value of input to submit, altough the radio button is hidden.